# I can't select Text and show a view based on selection in compose TextField

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I wrote a compose function with two BasicTextFields.
I want to show a part of the view based on select text in the textField but when I select it I think there is a recomposition issue and text is not selected. As you can see in the attached gif file when I select the text view blinks and text is not selected.

[image]

```
@Composable
fun AddEditNoteScreen(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    onBack: () -> Unit,
    onShowSnackbar: suspend (String) -> Boolean,
    viewModel: AddNoteViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
    val state by viewModel.uiState.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val scrollState = rememberScrollState()
    val focusManager = LocalFocusManager.current
    val openDatePicker = remember {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }
    val selectedTextLength = remember {
        mutableIntStateOf(0)
    }
    val configuration = LocalConfiguration.current
    val screenHeight = configuration.screenHeightDp.dp
    var titleValue: TextFieldValue by remember { mutableStateOf(value = TextFieldValue()) }
    var descriptionValue: TextFieldValue by remember { mutableStateOf(value = TextFieldValue()) }

    var openEditContentsHolder by remember {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }

    val openCloseDialog = remember {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }

    val showTimePicker = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val sheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState(skipPartiallyExpanded = true)
    val showBottomSheet = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    when (val uiState = state) {
        is AddNoteUiState.Data -> {
            LaunchedEffect(key1 = uiState.createOrUpdateNoteStatus) {
                if (uiState.createOrUpdateNoteStatus) {
                    scope.launch { onShowSnackbar(uiState.actionMessage) }
                }
            }
            LaunchedEffect(key1 = uiState.error) {
                if (uiState.error.isNotEmpty()) {
                    scope.launch {
                        onShowSnackbar(uiState.error)
                    }
                }
            }
            LaunchedEffect(key1 = uiState.note) {
                titleValue = TextFieldValue(uiState.note.title)
                descriptionValue = TextFieldValue(uiState.note.description ?: "")
            }
            BoxWithConstraints {
                val maxHeight = maxHeight
                Column(
                    modifier = modifier
                        .fillMaxSize()
                        .padding(28.dp)
                        .verticalScroll(scrollState),
                    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(40.dp)
                ) {
                    
                    Surface(
                        modifier = modifier.weight(1f),
                        shape = RoundedCornerShape(topStart = 24.dp, topEnd = 24.dp),
                        color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background,
                        shadowElevation = 1.dp
                    ) {
                        Column(
                            modifier = modifier
                                .fillMaxSize()
                                .padding(16.dp),
                            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(10.dp),
                            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
                        ) {
                            NoteBasicTextField(
                                value = titleValue,
                                updateTextValue = {
                                    titleValue = it
                                    selectedTextLength.intValue =
                                        it.selection.max - it.selection.min
                                    openEditContentsHolder = selectedTextLength.intValue > 0
                                },
                                textStyle = MaterialTheme.typography.headlineSmall.copy(fontSize = 20.sp),
                                placeholder = "Enter title",
                                keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(imeAction = ImeAction.Done),
                            )

                            NoteBasicTextField(
                                value = descriptionValue,
                                updateTextValue = {
                                    descriptionValue = it
                                    selectedTextLength.intValue =
                                        it.selection.max - it.selection.min
                                    openEditContentsHolder = selectedTextLength.intValue > 0
                                },
                                textStyle = MaterialTheme.typography.labelLarge.copy(fontSize = 13.sp),
                                placeholder = "Enter description",
                                keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(imeAction = ImeAction.Done),
                            )

                            Column(
                                modifier = modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
                                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(4.dp)
                            ) {
                                DatePickerInDatePickerDialog(
                                    openDialog = openDatePicker.value,
                                    onDismiss = { openDatePicker.value = false },
                                    selectedDate = { date ->
                                        date?.let {
                                            if (Instant.fromEpochMilliseconds(it)
                                                    .toLocalDateTime(TimeZone.currentSystemDefault()).date < Clock.System.now()
                                                    .toLocalDateTime(
                                                        TimeZone.currentSystemDefault()
                                                    ).date
                                            ) {
                                                scope.launch {
                                                    onShowSnackbar("Date is not valid")
                                                }
                                                return@let
                                            }
                                            viewModel.updateDueDate(
                                                Instant.fromEpochMilliseconds(it)
                                                    .toLocalDateTime(
                                                        TimeZone.currentSystemDefault()
                                                    ).date
                                            )
                                            scope.launch {
                                                onShowSnackbar("Date is selected")
                                            }
                                        }
                                    })
                            }
                            Column(
                                modifier = modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
                                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(4.dp)
                            ) {
                                TimePickerWithDialog(
                                    showTimePicker = showTimePicker.value,
                                    timePickerState = {
                                        viewModel.updateDueTime(
                                            time = TimeModel(
                                                it.hour,
                                                it.minute
                                            )
                                        )
                                    },
                                    onDismiss = { showTimePicker.value = false })

                            }
                        }
                    }


                }
                DateTimeSheet(
                    showBottomSheet,
                    modifier,
                    screenHeight,
                    sheetState,
                    uiState,
                    openDatePicker,
                    showTimePicker
                )

                CloseDialog(openCloseDialog, modifier, onBack)
                AnimatedVisibility(visible = openEditContentsHolder) {
                    focusManager.clearFocus()
                    Box(
                        modifier = modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth()

                            .padding(20.dp)
                    ) {
                        Surface(
                            modifier = modifier
                                .fillMaxWidth()
                                .height(56.dp),
                            shape = RoundedCornerShape(41.dp),
                            color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.scrim,
                            shadowElevation = 8.dp
                        ) {
                            Row(
                                modifier = modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceAround,
                                verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
                            ) {
                                Icon(
                                    painter = painterResource(id = com.sn.designsystem.R.drawable.edit),
                                    contentDescription = "edit"
                                )
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

```
@Composable
fun NoteBasicTextField(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    readOnly: Boolean = false,
    value: TextFieldValue,
    height: Dp = 54.dp,
    borderWidth: Dp = 1.dp,
    borderColor: Color = Color.Unspecified,
    borderShape: Shape = RoundedCornerShape(size = 5.dp),
    updateTextValue: (TextFieldValue) -> Unit,
    textStyle: TextStyle = TextStyle(
        fontSize = 16.sp,
        fontWeight = FontWeight.Medium,
        color = Color.DarkGray
    ),
    contentAlignment: Alignment = Alignment.CenterStart,
    visualTransformation: VisualTransformation = VisualTransformation.None,
    keyboardOptions: KeyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions.Default,
    keyboardActions: KeyboardActions = KeyboardActions.Default,
    singleLine: Boolean = false,
    label: @Composable (() -> Unit)? = null,
    placeholder: String = "",
    leadingIcon: @Composable (() -> Unit)? = null,
    trailingIcon: @Composable (() -> Unit)? = null,
) {
    Column(modifier = modifier.height(height)) {
        label?.let { it() }
        BasicTextField(
            modifier = modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            readOnly = readOnly,
            value = value,
            onValueChange = {
                updateTextValue(it)
            },
            visualTransformation = visualTransformation,
            keyboardActions = keyboardActions,
            keyboardOptions = keyboardOptions,
            singleLine = singleLine,
            textStyle = textStyle,
            decorationBox = { innerTextField ->
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxSize()
                        .border(
                            width = borderWidth,
                            color = borderColor,
                            shape = borderShape
                        )
                        .padding(horizontal = 16.dp, vertical = 8.dp),
                    contentAlignment = contentAlignment // Center the content vertically
                ) {
                    Row(
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
                        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(4.dp)
                    ) {
                        leadingIcon?.let { it() }
                        Box(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .weight(1f)
                        ) {
                            if (value.text.isEmpty()) {
                                Text(
                                    text = placeholder,
                                    style = LocalTextStyle.current.copy(
                                        fontSize = 16.sp,
                                        color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.outline
                                    ),
                                )
                            }
                            innerTextField()
                        }
                        trailingIcon?.let { it() }
                    }
                }
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is caused by `focusManager.clearFocus()` you are calling inside `AnimatedVisibility` block. For selecting to work properly `TextField` has to stay focused, otherwise selection is lost. So now every time you set openEditContentsHolder to true, you clear focus and selection is lost.

Remove `focusManager.clearFocus()`, it should work well.